# Compare 2 mysql tables

Tags: mysql, compare

I have 2 tables (t1 with 581978 rows,t2 with 581196 rows) containing some common fields (f1,f2,f3). The tables normally have the same number of rows, but can get out of sync.  When this happens I'd like to identify the rows in t1 that are not in t2.  The following python code (just use the 'select stmt' for mysql without python) identified the additional 782 rows in t1 but on my ageing iMac took over 12hrs!  Is there a more efficient method?

```
orphans = ("select t1.f1,t1.f2,t1.f3 from t1 where not exists " \
            "(select 1 from t2  where t2.f1=t1.f1 and t2.f2=t1.f2 and " \
            "t2.f3=t1.f3)")
cursor.execute(orphans)
for i,(f1,f2,f3) in enumerate(cursor):
    print(i+1,"orphans {:<10} {:<10} {<:8}".format(f1,f2,f3))
```

db-fiddle code (Is there a free db-fiddle, seems I can't save without upgrading to pro?)

```
CREATE DATABASE if not exists SO_61403216;
use SO_61403216;
drop table if exists t1,t2;
create table t1 (f1 varchar(1),f2 int(2),f3 int(2),f4 int(2));
create table t2 (f1 varchar(1),f2 int(2),f3 int(2),f4 int(2),f5 int(2));

insert into t1  (f1,f2,f3,f4) values ("A",2,3,4);
insert into t1  (f1,f2,f3,f4) values ("B",2,3,4);
insert into t1  (f1,f2,f3,f4) values ("C",2,3,4);
insert into t1  (f1,f2,f3,f4) values ("D",2,3,4);

insert into t2  (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) values ("A",2,3,44,55);
insert into t2  (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) values ("B",2,3,99,99);
insert into t2  (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) values ("C",2,3,99,99);
```

Query, which exposes the extra row in table t1 using both the "not exist" (preferred output) and "null" methods, which both take 0ms for these small tables, but same query takes hours with 500K+ rows - is there a better/quicker method?

```
use SO_61403216;
desc t1;
desc t2;
select * from t1; 
select * from t2;
select t1.f1,t1.f2,t1.f3 from t1 where not exists (select 1 from t2  where t2.f1=t1.f1 and t2.f2=t1.f2 and t2.f3=t1.f3)   
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.f1=t2.f1 and t1.f2=t2.f2 and t1.f3=t2.f3 where t2.f1 is null;
```

Comment: It's no quicker using a query from mysql, the python connection is not the problem. Thanks for the tip, I'll look into using sqlfiddle to provide some data.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a left join and a null test rather than a not exists.

Comment: Unable to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ - "SQL Fiddle Down for an Unknown Reason" has it been like this for long?

Comment: use db-fiddle instead

Comment: Using the NULL test now, it's been running over 75 mins without a result. Will try to knock out something on db-fiddle, thanks.

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes?

Comment: No indexes are used